# How to call locationManager didUpdateToLocation from the background?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

Hi I wanted to get the location of the user even when the app is in the background then I wanted to upload that info to the db and when the user runs the app again it will show him all the places he visited. So I read the article https://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial and did everything the author said In capabilities I added background modes location updates, I also set in info.plist application does not run in the background to NO but my app still does not run in the background what could be the problem?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit



class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var i = 0


    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!
    var backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance()
    lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        return locationManager
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        getLocations()
        self.map.showsUserLocation = true

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: -LocationManagerDelegate
    //func locationMana
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {
        let loc = MKPointAnnotation()
        loc.coordinate = newLocation.coordinate

        savelocation(loc.coordinate.longitude, latitude: loc.coordinate.latitude)
        //loc.coordinate.latitude
        //map.showAnnotations(loc, animated: true)

    }
    func savelocation(longitude: Double, latitude: Double){
        print("I work \(i)")
        i++
        let loc1 = locations()
        loc1.latitude = String(latitude)
        loc1.longitude = String(longitude)
       // print(loc1.latitude)
       // print(loc1.longitude)
        let datastore = backendless.data.of(locations.ofClass())
        var error: Fault?
        let result = datastore.save(loc1, fault: &error) as? locations
        if error == nil{
            print("data was saved")
        }else{
            print("data was not saved")
        }
    }
    func callAlert(message:String!){
        let alertController=UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let OKButton=UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(OKButton)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func getLocations(){
        var arr = [MKPointAnnotation]()
        //var temp: MKPointAnnotation!
        let dataStore = Backendless.sharedInstance().data.of(locations.ofClass())
        var error: Fault?
        let result = dataStore.findFault(&error)
        if error == nil{
            let locs = result.getCurrentPage()
            //     print(cities)
            let locs1 = locs as! [locations]
            if locs1.count - 1 >= 0{
                for index in 0...locs1.count - 1{
                    let temp = MKPointAnnotation()
                    temp.coordinate.latitude = Double(locs1[index].latitude!)!
                    temp.coordinate.longitude = Double(locs1[index].longitude!)!
                    arr.append(temp)
                }
                self.map.addAnnotations(arr)
            }
        }else{
            self.callAlert("There is an error retrieving data")
        }

    }


}
```

I tried also changing appdelegate applicationDidEnterBackground method but I don't know how to call that method manually. Any help? Thanks. :) P.s. I know that is illegal and app should call it itself but I don't see how can do it differently

Comment: I have a similar App that works fine. Your code looks good - do you have "Privacy - Location Always Usage Description" (`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`) in your info.plist?

Comment: Yes I do have that

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have set up your `locationManager` as a lazy var, and I'm assuming it gets initialized on this call: `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`. You should implement this method to start updates instead:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, 
                     didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status:
    case .AuthorizedAlways:
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    default:
        break
}
```

**Note:** This will at least let you know that you have properly authorized your app to use the user's location. You'll still need something to use your `lazy var locationManager` property in order to instantiate it. I would recommend using a regular property instead, and setting up your `locationManager` in `viewDidLoad`.